# What is this element in the .xml file?

Tags: android, android-layout

in this object dynamic movement occurs (moving of snake)
what is this object for?

i found this project in GitHub.
Code of this object:

```
<zhangman.github.snake.SnakePanelView
      android:id="@+id/snake_view"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      />
```

[screenshot of android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efvcd.png)

Comment: This must be a custom view, the usage should be provided in the source itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SnakePanelView** is a **custom view** made by some other developer that you are using as a dependency.

Just like other views like **ImageView** to display the images and **VideoView** to show the video media etc. **SnakePanelView** is there to show the movement of object(Snake).

For more info visit project website:

https://github.com/zhangman523/AndroidGameSnake

Answer (score 0):

It is a [Custom View](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) that the project author created for his custom needs. If you hold `Ctrl` and click on the `<zhangman.github.snake.SnakePanelView` tag, it will take you to its class implementation where you can see how this view was actually created.

Furthermore, you can follow this official [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-training-custom-view-from-scratch/index.html?index=..%2F..advanced-android-training#0) to learn how to create custom views step by step.